# Unable to flash anything using twrp. "Cannot mount/vendor"

Tags: twrp

I updated to the latest version of RR 6.0 (2018-04-05 security patch)using dirty flash. After updating I realised that I was not able to flash any zip. "Cannot mount/vendor" error was being shown. I also lost root (magisk) after the update.  Here is the digest file
Updating partition details...
done
Unable to mount storage
Full SELinux support is present.
Data successfully decrypted, new block device: '/dev
/block/dm-0
Updating partition details...
done
MTP Enabled
Installing zip file '/sdcard/DolbyAtmos_for_Oreo_
20180219.zip
Checking for Digest file...
Skipping Digest check: no Digest file found
! Cannot mount /vendor
Updater process ended with ERROR: 1
Error installing zip file '/sdcard/Dolby Atmos_for_Oreo_20180219.zip
Updating partition details...
done
Please help. It's the same for any zip(I was able to flash SuperSU but my phone did not get rooted)[image]

Comment: I remember I once had the same issue. Did you try to update your TWRP to the most recent version?

Comment: I am using the latest version. Is there any problem in the 2018-04-05 security patch that can cause it?

Comment: same problem here. Did anyone found anything?